# How do I provide an informal string representation of a python Class (not instance)

Tags: python

I understand how I can provide an informal representation of an *instance* of the object, but I am interested in providing an informal string representation of the Class name.

So specifically, I want to override what is returned when I print the Class (__main__.SomeClass).

```
>>> class SomeClass:
...   def __str__(self):
...     return 'I am a SomeClass instance.'
... 
>>> SomeClass
<class __main__.SomeClass at 0x2ba2f0fd3b30>
>>> print SomeClass
__main__.SomeClass
>>> 
>>> x = SomeClass()
>>> x
<__main__.SomeClass instance at 0x2ba2f0ff3f38>
>>> print x
I am a SomeClass instance.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is called meta class confusion. Of class A, if `A.__str__(self)` is a template for methods of instances of A, how can I provide a method `__str__()` for A itself? Meta classes to the rescue.

The following links explain this better than I could here.

http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/metaclass_1.html

http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/metaclass_2.html

A short example here:

```
class AMeta(type):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I am the truly remarkable class A"

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = AMeta
    def __str__(self):
        return "I am an A instance"

print A
I am the truly remarkable class A
print A()
I am an A instance
```

Btw you can do the same for `__repr__`.

Comment: I think you meant `def __str__(self):` in `class A` instead of `def str(self):`

Comment: If `repr(A)` is called when you define `__str__` it won't use your custimized message. However, if you define `__repr__` and `str(A)` is called, it __will__ use your custimized message if `str` isn't defined (which it isn't for `type`, the default metaclass).

Comment: @agif: I meant overriding `__repr__` for a *class* (repr(A)) requires the same meta class trick. There are fallbacks for serveral of these methods if one isn't defined at all, but that's a different topic and well documented in the std lib reference.

Answer (score 3):

you would have to override the `__str__` method of the *metaclass*.  I don't really know why you would want to do this, but here it is anyway.

```
>>> class InformalType(type):
...     def __str__(self):
...             return self.__name__
... 
>>> class MyFoo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = InformalType
...     pass
... 
>>> MyFoo
<class '__main__.MyFoo'>
>>> print MyFoo
MyFoo
>>> foo = MyFoo()
>>> foo
<__main__.MyFoo object at 0x7fdf9581f910>
>>> print foo
<__main__.MyFoo object at 0x7fdf9581f910>
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the class' string representation:

```
class MC(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'I am Test'

class Test:
    __metaclass__ = MC
   pass

print Test
```

works fine.

If `repr(Test)` is called when you define `__str__` it won't use your custimized message.

However, if you define `__repr__` like I did, and `str(Test)` is called, it **will** use your custimized message, because `__repr__` is the fallback and `__str__` isn't defined in `type`.

If all you want to do is change it's name:

```
def renamer(name):
    def wrapper(func):
        func.__name__ = name
        return func
    return wrapper

@renamer('Not Test')
class Test: pass
print Test.__name__

Test.__name__ = 'Test Again'
print Test.__name__
```

will both work to change the class' name.

Comment: He wants to change how the class is printed (as str), not its name.

Comment: Look at my first code example, it does exactly that. The second example is the one that changes the name. In fact, my answer had that before yours did.

Answer (score 1):

override `__repr__` instead.

```
>>> class SomeClass(object):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return 'I am a SomeClass instance.'
```

Comment: No, this overrides instance representation.

Comment: `__repr__` is for instances too. it doesn't do what he says, i tried decorating `__repr__` with @classmethod, but didn't work :).

Comment: Your code still doesn't work, because to be useful to repr(SomeClass), your `SomeClass.__repr__` must not have a self argument.

Comment: repr is used for the formal representation of an object. I'm looking for the informal representation of the Class.

Comment: I'm misunderstood the question

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with metaclasses.

Observe:

```
>>> class MyMeta(type):
...     def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
...             super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
...
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "MyMeta is Cool: " + self.__name__
...
>>> class FooType(metaclass=MyMeta):
...     pass
...
>>> FooType
MyMeta is Cool: FooType
```